# Install Wine Problem

Tags: installation, apt, windows, wine

I wan't to install wine in Ubuntu but  after type this sentence a message appear that says :

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command with superuser privileges.

So instead of `apt-get install wine`, type `sudo apt-get install wine`.

Comment: do you mean :
sudo apt-get wine.
or 
sudo apt-get install wine1.4-i386 ???
AnyWay it's told me that the first one is invalid operation 
and the second one have the same problem !!

Comment: @sosoma The latter one is correct. But it could be that you are already updating or installing something. You can also try to restart the computer. If this doesn't work than you have to delete the lockfile. See the question minerz029 linked above.

Comment: @sosoma Use `sudo apt-get install wine`. You missed the 'install' in your first command and your 2nd was a invalid package.

Comment: @minerz029 okay , i install it from software center , but when i execute exe file , it's show this message : 
err:module:import_dll Library MSVBVM60.DLL
so i download dll fixer , but it's given an error when i run it !!

Comment: @sosoma that's another question altogether, please ask another question